# ion-chip close triggers, ion-item button event

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a ion-item as a button and inside it I placed an ion-chip with a cross icon delete event. When ion-chip delete button is clicked, it triggers the ion-item event not ion-chip event. Even `event.stopPropogation` is not working.

How can I trigger the ion-chip onclick trigger event?

**activity.html**

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
     <button ion-item style="color: #999" (click)="addProject()">
      <span *ngIf="selected_project == null">Project</span>
      <div *ngIf="selected_project != null">
        <ion-chip color="primary">
          <span style="margin-left: 10px"><i class="fa fa-book">&nbsp;{{ selected_project.name }}</i></span>
          <button ion-button clear color="light" (click)="deleteProject($event)">
            <ion-icon name="close-circle"></ion-icon>
          </button>
        </ion-chip>
      </div>
      <ion-icon name="add" item-right></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-list>
<ion-content>
```

**activity.ts**

```
addProject(){
   //some code
}

deleteProject(event){
  event.stopPropagation(); //not working
}
```

Comment: Do you want both add and delete on the same item?

Comment: No. There a item on which I applied add event and inside that item I added a chip which is similar to badge but with an extra close button on it. On that close button I applied delete event. @skm

Comment: try `event.preventDefault()`...

Comment: not working @suraj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is not the propagation of the event, but the item being a button. Behind the scenes Ionic makes a lot of things to handle events from buttons, so in order to make it work, you can change the `ion-item` to be an item instead of a button with the attribute `ion-item`. Please take a look at **[this working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2W4tEf8qhM0ZLzvO0hkd?p=preview)**

By replacing the `<button ion-item ...></button>` by a `<ion-item tappable ...></ion-item>` the result from the UI point of view is exactly the same, but this time the `event.preventDefault()` will work properly.

**View**

```
  <ion-list>
     <ion-item tappable style="color: #999; cursor:pointer;" (click)="addProject($event)">
      <span *ngIf="selected_project == null">Project</span>
      <div *ngIf="selected_project != null">
        <ion-chip color="primary">
          <span style="margin-left: 10px"><i class="fa fa-book">&nbsp;{{ selected_project.name }}</i></span>
          <button ion-button clear color="light" (click)="deleteProject($event)">
            <ion-icon name="close-circle"></ion-icon>
          </button>
        </ion-chip>
      </div>
      <ion-icon name="add" item-right></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

**Component**

```
@Component({...})
export class HomePage {

  public  selected_project = { name: 'DemoProject'}

    constructor() {}

    public addProject(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert('Add project');
  }

  public deleteProject(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert('Delete project ');
  }

}
```

Comment: Glad to hear that! :)